# Is there a way to store the contents of a text file in a jagged string array in c?

Tags: arrays, c, text, file-io, io

Let's start with an example.txt file the contents of which are -

```
ABCDEF
ABCDE
ABCD
ABCDEFGH
ABC
A
AB
```

Array should look like -

```
arr = ["ABCDEF", "ABCDE", "ABCD", "ABCDEFGH", "ABC", "A", "AB"]
```

I need a way to store the lines in files similar to example.txt in a jagged character array in c. Is there a function that takes care of this or do I need to implement it manually. If I have to implement it manually, how do I allocate enough space on memory for the array when defining it?

Comment: Generally speaking, any question of the form "is it possible to do ..." can be answered by "yes". For your case what do you know about file input and how to read lines? What do you know bout pointers and dynamic memory allocation and *reallocation*? And what kind of research ave you done about jagged arrays in C and how to implement them?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm a C# Developer making the switch to C for a certain internship project. I know how to read characters in a file and print them onto the screen or store them in a string. I was wondering if my use case is common and someone has already worked on it. I tried searching but it led to no actual answers :(

Comment: Yes it's possible, and it's not uncommon. I suggest you invest in one or two beginners C books as all the subjects you need to learn should be covered there (pointer, `fgets`, `malloc`, `realloc`, etc.).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my dad probably has a K&R book, im guessing that should be more than enough for my use case?

Comment: *Maybe*... :) C have evolved over the years, the old C is not the same as the new C, but as long as the book is newer than about 30 years it should be good enough. :)

Comment: That K&R book might be considered both as "The C bible" and "Horribly outdated" at the same time. ;) If you come across implicit function declaration or using `gets`, cover your eyes!

Comment: Don't try to learn C with the K&R. Its dialekt is so outdated, you can compare it with smoke signals to communicate. There are tons of web-based opportunities, the main problem is to filter out the crap. See the info on the tag "C", it include hints.

Comment: The second edition is okay, and it's been updated with the (then new) "ANSI C". While C has evolved since then, the "core" of the language haven't changed that much. Everything in the second edition book is still as valid today as it was then.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

- Open the file and verify that `fopen` succeeded.
- Allocate an array of pointers by `char** array = malloc(n * sizeof(*array));` where `n` is some suitable value (100 pointers?).
- Keep track of the size used in the pointer array with some `size` variable.
- Start loop.
- Read a string into a "large enough" local buffer of 128 or 256 etc characters, using `fgets` or similar. Always check the result of the input function to see if it succeeded.
- If `size` < `n` then access `array[size]` and have it point at a `malloc(strlen(the_local_buffer))` chunk, then `strcpy` the local buffer data into that chunk.
- If `size == n` then realloc `array`.
- `size++` and loop.